# Change Background color of a component

Tags: xm-cloud

I'm new to `Sitecore XMCloud`. I am trying to make a partial design of a footer for a website.

Somehow, I selected a Dark `Background color` for the footer, and now I cannot undo it.

I am not sure where I was when I set it, whether in the Pages editor, the Experience Editor, or the Content Editor.

I have looked everywhere and do not see where that is set, but now everything I add as a footer to the page will have a dark background, and I cannot figure out how to either undo that, override it, or even make the font of words white so that they show up.

I have tried deleting the partial design and adding new ones, but no matter what, the basic page template has anything going in the footer section as dark.

I cannot see where to change the most basic base page design template either.  I know this is probably a simple question, but I am a bit overwhelmed by all of the options in the different editors.

Comment: How are you selecting the background color? Is this in the component builder?

Answer (score 1):

This would mainly depend on how you are applying background color. So first thing we can check is how it is configured in Sitecore. I would suggest you to check few things,

- `Datasource Item` : Please check if it has any field to specify background color. If yes, do confirm if it is being populated from *standard value*. You can try creating a new datasource item and see what changes.
- `Component Properties` : There are 2 things to look here. `Rendering Parameters` and `Paint Bucket Styles`. Background related value can be specified here as well.

Mostly you should find your problem here itself. If you don't then there is a *rare possibility that somethings happening* with `custom styles`.
Just inspect page elements to locate where *dark* background property is set. And now you can investigate how is it set ?

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.  Where am I checking these things?  In the Pages Editor, Content Editor, or Experience Editor?  And what item am I checking?  Is there a base page template to look at?  Any screenshots would help if possible.

Comment: All these properties belong to a rendering, so you can check it in Experience editor as well as content editor.